# Wrong file extension while uploading an image into server from android device

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova

I am trying to upload an image from android device gallery into server. But the selected image extension is not in a form of jpg/png/gif. It is storing with some unknown name as "image%3A55766". Could someone help me in acheving this. Thanks in advance. The same code is working fine with iOS device. I tried this upto now.

```js
<script>
function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { 
  quality: 25,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
 });
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey="file";
 options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
 options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
 var params = new Object();
 options.params = params;
 var ft = new FileTransfer();  
 ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://server.net/project/php/uploads.php"), win, fail, options);      
}

function win(r) {
 console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
 console.log("Response = " + r.response);
 console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
}  

function fail(error) {
 alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);     
}      
</script>

document.getElementById('gal1').innerHTML='<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM)"><img src="../images/gallery.png"></a>';
```

The following is the information I'm getting in my Logcat:

```html
File locaton is: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot_2016-05-13-21-56-20.png
upload content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A55766 to http://server.net/project/php/uploads.php
fileKey: file
fileName: image%3A55766
mimeType: image/jpeg
params: {}
trustEveryone: false
chunkedMode: true
headers: null
objectId: 1
httpMethod: POST
Content Length: 259650
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that this issue could be due to the way you are fetching the imageURI. Thats why this could be working fine in iOS but not in Android as file system is handled differently in both this OS. We manage to solve a similar issue sometime back. The problem was with filename setting. Request you to have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025867/name-of-picture-uploaded-with-file-phonegap-plugin-imagea3456/).

Hope it helps.