# How to upload a profile photo with file-transfer plugin for an iOS cordova app?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm working on an iOS Cordova app, I would like to change the profile picture using file-transfer plugin, I just want to select a photo from my phone's library and uploaded to the server: I'v tried this, its doesn't work, I appreciate any help, I'll provide other details if needed :)

```
function loadPicture()
{
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, function(message) { alert ("Ouups!"); }, { destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, quality: 80
 });

  function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    //alert(imageURI.toString());
    var myDate = new Date();
    var date = myDate.getFullYear() +"-" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)  +"-" + myDate.getUTCDate() +"_" + myDate.getHours() + "-" + myDate.getMinutes() + "-" + myDate.getSeconds();
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    var userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");

    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = "photo-" + userid + "-" + date + ".jpeg";
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    var params = {};
    params.userid = localStorage.getItem("userid");
    params.date = date;
    params.account = "user";
    options.params = params;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://62.210.192.92/AE/web/upload.php"), win, fail, options);

    alert("Done", "", "Profile picture");
    reload();
    var win = function (r) {}
    var fail = function (error) {}
  }
  function onFail(error) {}

}
```

Comment: Could you post error trace? Request you to have a look at this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025867/name-of-picture-uploaded-with-file-phonegap-plugin-imagea3456 This post has the working code

Comment: Tank you for your response, i'm getting no error with the error trace, I'm working actually on the app on both platforms iOS.android, the same code works fine with android platform but not iOS!

Comment: try using safari web inspector. There will be console error for sure.

Comment: I'v already done that, I'm getting no error's with the web inspector, i'v tried uploading an image with the same code using the android platform this time, I Can upload the image ' it works just fine' and the photo also changes in the iOS app, means that the error's from the upload code, once the photo is the server, i can get it and show it just fine!

Comment: Hey, I'v managed to get it work, just by reinstalling the plugin file-transfer, But its doesn't work on all photos, on some of them works just fine, on others no !!!

Comment: Better try installing latest file plugin too.

Comment: I did, the same thing, works on two picture from my phone library, I was gonna say that it could be size limit, but that before i changed the quality to 30!

Comment: its working on one or two pictures, not all the time, the 3rd try or the 4th, so weird!!!

Comment: Could be a server side issue then?

Comment: I dont think, I'v tested the same exact code, (the function and the upload.php) on the android platform, its works just fine!!

Comment: Could it be storage space issue in device by any chance?

Comment: I'v checked,  I have enough storage space in both phone and  server

Comment: I think it's probably a compatibility issue, on the platform iOS, if it didn't work on android I'll know for sure, thats a problem in my code. but here just on iOS, could you please, send me a clean code with the same parameters as mine (if you please can test it before), I'v searched the internet  but i didn't manage to get any code work, thank you in advance, can you send me the version of the plugin you used as well, I'll use the same, thank you again

Comment: I m sorry to say that i m not a PHP guy. But as i sent earlier, the post in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025867/name-of-picture-uploaded-with-file-phonegap-plugin-imagea3456 seems to be working. Can share file download or file creation code in cordova app if you want. But have not tried file upload personally.